# How can I iterate over a pandas dataframe so I can divide specific values based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
          0       1       2   ...      62      63   64
795     89.0    92.0    89.0  ...    74.0    64.0  4.0
575     80.0    75.0    78.0  ...    70.0    68.0  3.0
1119  2694.0  2437.0  2227.0  ...  4004.0  4010.0  6.0
777     90.0    88.0    88.0  ...    71.0    67.0  4.0
506     82.0    73.0    77.0  ...    69.0    64.0  2.0
...      ...     ...     ...  ...     ...     ...  ...
65      84.0    77.0    78.0  ...    78.0    80.0  0.0
1368  4021.0  3999.0  4064.0  ...     1.0  4094.0  8.0
1036    80.0    80.0    79.0  ...    73.0    66.0  5.0
1391  3894.0  3915.0  3973.0  ...     4.0  4090.0  8.0
345     81.0    74.0    75.0  ...    80.0    75.0  1.0
```

I want to divide all elements over 1000 in this dataframe by 100. So `4021.0` becomes `40.21`, et cetera.

I've tried something like below:

```py
for cols in df:
    for rows in df[cols]:
        print(df[cols][rows])
```

I get index out of bound errors. I'm just not sure how to properly iterate the way I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think loops are here slow, so better is use vectorizes solutions - select values greater like `1000` and divide:

```
df[df.gt(1000)] = df.div(100)
```

Or using [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df.mask(df.gt(1000), df.div(100))
```

---

```
print (df)
     0      1      2     62     63   64
795   89.00  92.00  89.00  74.00  64.00  4.0
575   80.00  75.00  78.00  70.00  68.00  3.0
1119  26.94  24.37  22.27  40.04  40.10  6.0
777   90.00  88.00  88.00  71.00  67.00  4.0
506   82.00  73.00  77.00  69.00  64.00  2.0
65    84.00  77.00  78.00  78.00  80.00  0.0
1368  40.21  39.99  40.64   1.00  40.94  8.0
1036  80.00  80.00  79.00  73.00  66.00  5.0
1391  38.94  39.15  39.73   4.00  40.90  8.0
345   81.00  74.00  75.00  80.00  75.00  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the applymap function and create your custom function

```
def mapper_function(x):
    if x >= 1000:
        x=x/100
        
    else:
       x
 return x

df=df.applymap(mapper_function)
```